# Django and models with different table names

Tags: python, django, django-models

Currently I'm in the design phase of creating a new application for championship tables. The goal is to provide an application where that game results of various leagues can be entered in a backend and the final tables are viewed in the frontend. As database I'd like to use PostgreSQL since it offers schemas to seperate differ between the leagues. The current schema will (most probably) look like:

```
= schema ==== tablename ==============
- public  ___ teams
- league1 ___ league1_<season>_results
           |_ league1_<season>_tables
- league2 ___ league2_<season>_results
           |_ league2_<season>_tables
- league3 ___ league3_<season>_results
           |_ league3_<season>_tables

<season> ... 2019, 2020, ...
```

As well as leagueX_*results as leagueX*_tables will have the same model, meaning _results in league 1 has the same layout as _results in league2, _tables in league1 is the same model in league2.

The `_tables` are (re)created using Pandas as man in the middle to compute the tables (this part is already working and in the drawer). The only thing I'm still looking for is the possibility to change the tablename (dynamically) to be used within the same model.

Unfortunately I'm not (yet) familiar with the Django framework, I was using Flask and SQLAlchemy before. For this combination I may have some slight idea how to solve this, but for this project I'm considering using Django as framework instead of wiring loose ends together since the integrity of some parts (permissions, ...) are much better and it looks more comprehensive.

So, I'd like to ask the community if someone may have had some similar challenge and how it may have been solved.

Many thanks in advance, regards, Thomas

Comment: Please reply to this query: will django have any part in table creation or django will just simply use the tables created by pandas (i.e. django won't create those table rather use the existing ones)?

Comment: The creation of the `_result` table will be done through the backend, i.e. preparing the next season. The `_tables` table is created through Pandas since its interface only supports either append or recreate, but not update.

Answer (score 0):

In order to server your purpose(I am considering that you have the similar fields in both tables created by pandas and django), first create one abstract model then inherit the model in two separate models - one managed and one unmanaged. Django ORM will be responsible for table creation and management of the managed model and pandas will be responsible for the unmanaged one. Django can still access and manipulate the unmanaged model's records if you allow it(by default it's allowed). Following can be a good example -

```py
class MyAbstractBaseModel(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class MyDjangoModel(MyAbstractBaseModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "mymodel_result"


class MyPandasModel(MyAbstractBaseModel):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "mymodel_table"
        managed = False
```

If you have separate definitions for the tables then just define your pandas model as your requirement and set `managed = False` in meta option. Also don't forget to explicitly mention the `db_table` option with your actual table name(for both django and pandas model). For more information about modle meta options please refer to the doc page -

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/options/

If your tables reside on separate databases also consider following - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/